# body width and inline-block elements

Tags: html, css

I have some `inline-block` elements that give the page a certain width. I would have thought that the `header` and `footer` tags would pick up the width - but they only have width of the browser. Why is that? And how to give them the full width of the page?

http://jsfiddle.net/Ft5dC/

html:

```
<body>
  <header>
  HEADER
  </header>

  <ol>
    <li><img src="img/slides/boy.jpg"/></li>
    <li><img src="img/slides/bridge.jpg"/></li>
    <li><img src="img/slides/guitar.jpg"/></li>
    <li><img src="img/slides/iphone.jpg"/></li>
  </ol>

  <footer>
  FOOTER
  </footer>
</body>
```

css:

```
  * {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  body {
    background-color: gray;
  }
  header {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  footer {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  ol {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap; 
    font-size: 0;
    background-color: blue;
  }
  li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    white-space: normal;
  }
  img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 40px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header and footer are really at 100%. The list items overflow outside of the body. This causes the canvas to be bigger and 100% looking like it is not the full width. As OdraEncoded suggested, setting the body to `inline-block` makes the body take up the full width of the canvas. This means the 100% width of header/footer now cover the full width.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are asking.

If you want the entire page to have the width of the largest element, add this CSS

```
body { display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It answers the how but not the why though.

Comment: what I am asking: the inline-block of the ol li should create block content that give the full width to the parent tag (body in this case). header and footer (at least if explicitly set to 100% width) should spread across the full width - not just the browser with.